# How to prevent adding/editing with AttachmentEditor?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, attachments

I have a WAB (for developers, version 1.4, JS API 3.16) widget with an AttachmentEditor. Depending on the user's privileges (managed through MVC), I want to prevent some of the users from modifying the attachments (this I can do by hiding the editor) and still showing them the attachments, but I found no way to let the editor show the attachments without permitting the user to add/delete them. Do I need to hack the editor code and use the tweaked version, or is there any clean option to do this? Bypassing AttachmentEditor completely seems to be the hardest way, so I hope it is not necessary.

I reposted this on [Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/message/613220).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer on Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/message/613220), thanks to Yusuf Ali!

Step 1, hide deleting:

```
.deleteAttachment{display:none;}
```

Step 2, prevent adding new attachments:

```
dojo.query('> div > form', dojo.byId("attachment-editor-container")).style('display', 'none');
```

Step 3, hide parentheses left after hiding the delete icons:

```
var spans = dojo.query('> div > span > span', dojo.byId("attachment-editor-container"));  
for(var i = 0, sl = spans.length; i < sl; i++) {  
    spans[i].innerHTML = spans[i].innerHTML.replace(/[()]/g, '');  
}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted. It's OK to accept your own answer.